# How to set and use session variables in pentaho CDE?

Tags: session-variables, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I'm trying to use session variables in CDE. I use Startup Rule Engine to set the variables (althought I'm not sure if it really works, since I haven't been able to access these variables yet). I want to use these variables on the preExecution of a component in CDE. I have tried with ${[session:region]} (region is the name of the variable) but I only get the text itself (if I use console.log). I have also set a simple parameter (name:region value:${[session:region]}) but I get the same.

What's the way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Assumption you are using MySQL database.

step1: Create one datasource

```
   Name: username
   Query:    SELECT ${env::username}
```

Step2: Goto component panel and then select `Select Component`. Fill up below details.

```
Name: selectvalue
Query name: username
HtmlObject: username(these is HTML id eg: <html> <div id=username> </div> </html>)
```

step3: Save your dashboard run and see

Thank you

Comment: I haven't tried it, but, finally, I could access the value creating a datasource with a parameter and using the resultset on the PostFetch of a  query component.